# Tried to use permissions API while not attached to an activity

Tags: react-native, react-native-camera, react-native-permissions

I am trying to save captured picture to my device gallery and fetch it back to display in my project. But the mean issue here is permission deny issue. I have setup "AndroidManifest.xml" with these: 


 but still I still get error, here is my code....

```js
render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
          <RNCamera
            ref = {ref=>{
                this.camera=ref;
            }}
            style={styles.preview}
            flashMode={this.state.flashon}
            type={this.state.backCamera ? RNCamera.Constants.Type.back : RNCamera.Constants.Type.front} 
            captureAudio={this.state.captureAudio}
            androidCameraPermissionOptions={{
              title: 'Vocajam needs ermission to use camera',
              message: 'We need your permission to use your camera',
              buttonPositive: 'Ok',
              buttonNegative: 'Cancel',
            }}
          >
              {
                ({ camera, status, androidRecordAudioPermissionOptions }) => {
                  if (status !== 'READY') return <PendingView />
```

I know there's something am not doing, but cant figuring it out, I need help on this issue...screenshot here [Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXt2C.png)

Comment: I have solved the issue, I have to explicitly ask for permission. I will post the code here

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out by asking for permission. I solved it with this code below:

```js
checkAndroidPermission = async () => {
    try {
      const permission = PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE;
      await PermissionsAndroid.request(permission);
      Promise.resolve();
    } catch (error) {
      Promise.reject(error);
    }
};

    takePicture = async () => {
        if (this.camera) {
          if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
            await this.checkAndroidPermission();
          }
            const options = { quality: 1 };
            const data = await this.camera.takePictureAsync(options);
            //save photo
            CameraRoll.save(data.uri, 'photo').then(onfulfilled => {
                ToastAndroid.show(onfulfilled, ToastAndroid.SHORT);
            }).catch(error => {
                ToastAndroid.show(`${error.message}`, ToastAndroid.SHORT);
            });
        }
    };
```